# How to use the REQUIRES parameter in a MODULE creation - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, module, requirements

The syntax for usage of a module is:

```
angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);
```

The **Type** for the `[requires]` **parameter** is:

```
!Array.<string>=
```

I have no idea what that means.  What does the exclamation point signify, that it's NOT an Array?  Why is there an equal sign at the end?  What is the period for?

Looking at another Stackoverflow question, the `[requires]` parameter is used to list other modules that this module uses.  So, is this sort of like an `Include` statement, that puts another module inside of this module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Google Closure Compiler [Type Expressions](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types) syntax.

- `Array.<string>` means an array of strings
- `!` at the beginning means it cannot be `null`
- `=` at the end means it is optional

Combine them together and we got: `!Array.<string>=` means it can be

- an `array of strings`
- an `empty array`
- `undefined` (optional)

But it cannot be `null`